# ngrx - Prevent Effects from bootstrapping before user login

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-services, ngrx-effects

I'm having an issue with NgRx Effects bootstrapping before the user logs in, which is causing my services to be instantiated with wrong headers (cause after log in, I set a couple cookies and use them to set the headers, as those services are initialised before log in, they don't have the headers).

I have a huge application and only a couple of features are using NgRx.

When the user logs in, it gets routed and another module is initialised. The legacy features (and it's modules) inside this workspace module then are initialised and every service is instantiated correctly (cause I have the data I need already set to use for the headers).
But my NgRx features, also inside this workspace module, are initialised on app start, not on module route.

This happens due to NgRx going over my Effects, which have the services injected. So the services I have inside my Effects are instantiated before login.

I went over a couple GitHub issues and articles and this is a known discussion, but the needs approached by the people that wrote those issues and articles are different than mine and I wasn't able to figure out by myself how to take the answers and do something for my problem.
The articles are about `APP_INITIALIZER` and `Effects` bootstrap not respecting it ([#931](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/931), [#174](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/174), [NgRx docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/api.md#onruneffects), [Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e) and [itnext](https://itnext.io/angular-app-initializer-ngrx-1d1340532fe3))

How can I work with that to make my Effects wait for something?

(Ps: Is there a NgRx life cycle docs for me to understand what's going on under the hood?)

Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't the hook `OnRunEffects` work for you?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I'm afraid I'm not sure I understood how this works reading by the docs (https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/api.md#controlling-effects) and wanted or a reference to, as I asked for, the life cycle or to people to discuss with me. I'll right now try to read more about that and maybe it will fit me, but I still would like to understand the big picture of that. Real thanks.

Comment: It will only execute the effects after the LOGIN action. Once there is a LOGOUT action, it won't execute anymore.

Comment: And it would create a giant boilerplate as I keep rewriting the legacy features into ngrx, right? Any work around that?

Comment: I think you should be able to create a custom RxJS operator, to prevent writing the same code.